# Javascript template or another solution?

Tags: javascript, html, templates

New to webdev.

I need to use the same menu on all the pages of new website i'm building but I'm not willing to edit the menu every time a change it in every file.

Is there a simple template engine for javascript or another solution to fix this issue?

Comment: This problem is usually solved by your web framework, though it's achievable via JavaScript, too.  Are you using a web development framework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML code reuse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009563/html-code-reuse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the menu is dynamically constructed via your website, then you're best bet is to use server-side templates.

In PHP you can do:

```
include("menu.php");
```

Wherever you need it to display.

In JavaScript, if you need to style the menu, then check out [Mustache.JS](http://mustache.github.com) or similar.

Comment: Thank you but at the moment I'm only able to use javascript, I don't have php support.